# enable a disabled html button based in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to enable below button based on the boolean value from context i.e. {{ enable }}.
if enable is True then make it enable otherwise disabled.

```
<input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" disabled/>
```

Comment: `{% if enable %} <input type="submit" ... /> {% else %} <input type="submit" ... disabled /> {% endif %}` I think that this is the simplest way to do that if you are not going to handle it dynamically with other events on browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering but can I include django tag in html tag as an attribute ? like        <input type="submit " {% if enable %} disabled {% endif %}>

Comment: I already commented for it. :) Yes. you can. You can try that in person though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this:

```
{% if enable %}
<input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />

{% else %}
<input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" disabled/>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but can I include django tag in html tag as attribute ? like <input type="submit " {%if enable%}disabled{% endif %}>

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to do that is:

```
<input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" 
       value="Upload" {% if not enable %}disabled{%endif%} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to disable the button based on the condition in Django.

```
     <input type="button" {% if a==b %} disabled="true" {% endif %}/>
```

Here 'a' and 'b' refers to the variables coming from the Django view.